# Contact license key server with Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

Using the Pascal scripting, is there any way to connect to a server and send/retrieve data over http? Browsing through the reference I didn't see any way...

Comment: A lot of programs seem to put license key management functionality into the application, rather than into the installer. So it may be worth considering that option instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to put that functionality in a DLL and call it from within the Inno-script. There are definitely no HTTP-support functions out of the box.

Comment: what ended up helping were the "isxdl" extensions which enable you to download files and such. It's included with ISTool.